# Plot a continuous graph of Number of Snort alerts against time

Tags: python-3.x, redis, snort, syslog-ng

I have snort logging DDOS alerts to file; I use Syslog-ng to parse the logs and output in json format into redis (wanted to set it up as a buffer, I use 'setex' command with expiry of 70 secs).

The whole thing seems not to be working well; any ideas to make it easier is welcome.

I wrote a simple python script to listen to redis KA events and count the number of snort alerts per second. I tried creating two other threads; one to retrieve the json-formatted alerts from snort and the second to count the alerts. The third is supposed to plot a graph using matplotlib.pyplot

```py
#import time 
from redis import StrictRedis as sr 
import os
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import threading as th
import time


redis = sr(host='localhost', port = 6379, decode_responses = True)


#file = open('/home/lucidvis/vis_app_py/log.json','w+')

# This function is still being worked on
def  do_plot():
    print('do_plot loop running')
    while accumulated_data:

        x_values = [int(x['time_count']) for x in accumulated_data]
        y_values = [y['date'] for y in accumulated_data]

        plt.title('Attacks Alerts per time period')

        plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=14)
        plt.ylabel('Snort Alerts/sec')

        plt.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=14)

        plt.plot(y_values,x_values, linewidth=5)
        plt.show()
        time.sleep(0.01)




def accumulator():
    # first of, check the current json data and see if its 'sec' value is same 
    #that is the last in the accumulated data list
    #if it is the same, increase time_count by one else pop that value
    pointer_data = {}

    print('accumulator loop running')

    while True: 
        # pointer data is the current sec of json data used for comparison
        #new_data is the latest json formatted alert received
        # received_from_redis is a list declared in the main function
        if received_from_redis:
            new_data = received_from_redis.pop(0)
        if not pointer_data:
            pointer_data = new_data.copy()

        print(">>", type(pointer_data), " >> ", pointer_data)

        if pointer_data and pointer_data['sec']==new_data["sec"]
            pointer_data['time_count'] +=1


        elif pointer_data: 
            accumulated_data.append(pointer_data)
            pointer_data = new_data.copy()
            pointer_data.setdefault('time_count',1)

        else:
            time.sleep(0.01)




# main function creates the redis object and receives messages based on events
#this function calls two other functions and creates threads so they appear to run concurrently

def main():
    p = redis.pubsub()
    # 
    p.psubscribe('__keyspace@0__*')

    print('Starting message loop')

    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(2)
            message = p.get_message()

    # Obtain the key from the redis emmitted event if the event is a set event
            if message and message['data']=='set':
         # the format emmited by redis is in a dict form
         # the key is the value to the key 'channel'
         # The key is in '__keyspace@0__*' form
         # obtain the last field of the list returned by split function
                key = message['channel'].split('__:')[-1]

                data_redis = json.loads(redis.get(str(key)))
                received_from_redis.append(data_redis)
        except Exception e:
            print(e)

            continue




if __name__ == "__main__":
    accumulated_data = []
    received_from_redis = []
# main function creates the redis object and receives messages based on events
#this function calls two other functions and creates threads so they appear to run concurrently
    thread_accumulator = th.Thread(target = accumulator, name ='accumulator')
    do_plot_thread = th.Thread(target = do_plot, name ='do_plot')

    while True:
        thread_accumulator.start()
        do_plot_thread.start()

        main()

    thread_accumulator.join()
    do_plot_thread.join()
```

I currently do get errors per se ; I just cant tell if the threads are created or are working well. I need ideas to make things work better.

sample of the alert formated in json and obtained from redis below

```
{"victim_port":"","victim":"192.168.204.130","protocol":"ICMP","msg":"Ping_Flood_Attack_Detected","key":"1000","date":"06/01-09:26:13","attacker_port":"","attacker":"192.168.30.129","sec":"13"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand exactly your scenario, but if you want to count events that are essentially log messages, you can probably do that within syslog-ng. Either as a [Python destination](http://support.oneidentity.com/technical-documents/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.21/administration-guide/destination-forward-send-and-store-log-messages/python-writing-custom-python-destinations) (since you are already working in python), or maybe even without additional programming using the [grouping-by parser](http://support.oneidentity.com/technical-documents/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.21/administration-guide/correlating-log-messages/correlating-messages-using-the-grouping-by-parser).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; reading about 'grouping-by'  and python destination currently.

Basically, the requirements of the project is that,  a bar/line chart representing number of snort alerts(DOS attack packets detection) per second in real time. I wish snort could produce such a metric but i cant figure it out. 

Secondly, A graph with nodes representing attacker and victim with number_of_snort_alerts / second as the weight of the connecting edge

Comment: I think you can do the first one with grouping-by (you might have to play a bit with the timeout if the alerts are frequent), but surely with python, and then you can send an aggregated message about the alerts to redis. For the second, I guess you'll have to use python, but you might be able to come up with a suitable grouping-by + template functions combo.